# OAuth2 returns invalid_client error

Tags: php, curl, oauth, box-api

good day,

I'm having trouble with getting the access token. I've followed the guide here: http://developers.box.com/oauth/
and already get my **client_id**, **client_secret**, and set the **redirect_uri** on the App settings (*OAuth2 parameters*) section.

Here is the code for the file **client.php**

```
<?php
    $client_id = 'my_client_id_here'; //removed
    $post_url = 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize';

    include 'includes/header.php';
?>
    <div id="content">
        <form action="<?php echo $post_url; ?>" type="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="text" name="response_type" value="code">
            <input type="text" name="client_id" value="<?php echo $client_id; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="state" value="vexhax97td8xf_SomeTemporaryValueForTesting">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </div>

<?php
    include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

and here's code for the file **something.php** (this is where the **redirect_uri** will go)

```
<?php

$client_id =  'my_client_id_here'; //removed
$client_secret =  'my_client_secrect_here'; //removed
$post_url = 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token';

$code = $_GET['code'];

include 'includes/header.php';

$fields_params = array(
        "grant_type" => 'authorization_code',
        "code" => $code,
        "client_id" => $client_id,
        "client_secret" => $client_secret
    );

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($json);

?>
    <div id="content">
        <?php 
            //Nothing fancy, just for displaying passed values
            if (isset($_GET))
                var_dump($_GET); 

            if (isset($_POST))
                var_dump($_POST); 
        ?>
    </div>

<?php
    include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

...now what happens is,

1.) on the first step (**client.php**), there is a form there with submit button.

2.) After i clicked on the submit button, i get redirected to the Box' login page with the button "Authorize".

3.) after entering login details and allow granting access for my app. I now gets redirected to the **redirect_uri** that i've set on the App settings (**something.php**), where in this file, it will execute curl post to get an access token, but i get stuck at this part, the curl result returns with the error:

```
array(2) { ["error"]=> string(14) "invalid_client" ["error_description"]=> string(34) "The client credentials are invalid" }
```

I'm sure that I have entered my **client_id** and **client_secret** correctly which I've obtained from the App settings. And the url for the **redirect_uri**, is also SSL enabled.

Any solutions, ideas why this is happening?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the cURL headers you're setting `something.php`. Remove the `Content-Type` header. In fact, you can not set the headers at all - cURL will send the correctly encoded parameters and Box will return JSON data by default.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json'
));
```

Comment: You just made my day!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I received the token in JS

```
authorizeUser = function(){    

        var results = $.ajax({

            // The URL to process the request
            url : 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                grant_type : 'authorization_code',
                code : data.boxAuthorizationCode,
                client_id : data.clientId,
                client_secret : data.clientSecret
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
               //console.log(response);
               console.log(response.access_token);
               data.access_token = response.access_token;
               tokenGranted();
            }

        });

        return results.responseText;

    },
```